# How to set up LaTeX document

Tags: latex

I write my thesis in LaTeX. I want to set up the document to have 60 symbols per line and 30 lines per page. How to do this?

Comment: Take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: (La)TeX-related questions are better asked at [tex.se]. I've flagged your question so that it gets migrated there.

Answer (score 2):

I would say this goes against LaTeX principles: don't concern yourself with these futilities, and just write your text. LaTeX will typeset your document `The Right Way (TM)`.

Comment: And I think so, but in our faculty this is such a requirement.

Comment: Then they most likely have a LaTeX template to do what they think is right. Ask about it. I'm not even sure this is strictly possible in stuff like Word.

Comment: That sort of overspecification is better typeset with a typewriter than with LaTeX